# How can I set an input field in rails to be to new Date(); from js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date, datefield, input-field

My page has this js to try and set the field:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/time_locally.js?body=1">
  var localTime = new Date();
  $('#time_locally').val(localTime); 
</script>
```

and the form

```
simple_form_for(@link) do |f|
```

has this field:

```
= f.text_field :local_time, id: 'time_locally'
```

Yet the field doesn't get the local date time (see last field, long and blank).

It currently gets display as

```
<input id="time_locally" type="text" size="30" name="link[local_time]"></input>
```

How can I make it do that?

[image]

I tried changing to classs but that didn't help.
I am sure the js start to fire because I can `alert(localTime)` and get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The id of the element will be link_local_time, I don't think you can overwrite the id attribute. But you can use a class instead.

So use `$('#link_local_time').val(localTime);`

or set a class on the element

`= f.text_field :local_time, class: 'time_locally'`

and change your js to

`$('.time_locally').val(localTime);`

Comment: I tried changing to class but that didn't help.  Update above.